# merge multiple files with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, merge, jaxb

It's the first time I'm using stackoverflow and I don't speak English perfectly so be nice please.

I'm using Jaxb in append mode like that

```
for (Document330 document : documents){
  JAXBContext jContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Document330Xml.class);
    Marshaller m = jContext.createMarshaller();
    m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
    m.marshal(document, fos);
}
```

And I have an output file like that:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <MAILING>
        <REF>M584</REF>
        <LIBELLE>Mail Test 1</LIBELLE>
    </MAILING>
</DOCUMENT>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DOCUMENT>
    <MAILING>
        <REF>M585</REF>
        <LIBELLE>Mail Test 2</LIBELLE>
    </MAILING>
</DOCUMENT>
```

but I want something like that :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<DOCUMENTS>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <MAILING>
            <REF>M584</REF>
            <LIBELLE>Mail Test 1</LIBELLE>
        </MAILING>
    </DOCUMENT>
    <DOCUMENT>
        <MAILING>
            <REF>M585</REF>
            <LIBELLE>Mail Test 2</LIBELLE>
        </MAILING>
    </DOCUMENT>
</DOCUMENTS>
```

But it is possible that I have many XML. So I do not think the Unmarshaller is the best solution

Thanks for reading me

Comment: You simply write multiple ``String``s to the same outputstream. What have you tried to wrap those 2 ``DOCUMENT``s in a ``DOCUMENTS`` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remind correctly, you need to create a `Documents330Xml` class, which can be marshalled (you can have a look at your `Document330Xml` class for reference). This class needs a list of `Document330Xml` as field.

If you then marshall the `Documents330Xml` class, you should get the desired XML.