# How to merge two XML into one using JAX-B?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have two xml files (A.xml and B.xml):

```
<Root>
    <A>
        <name>number</name>
        <value>8</value>
    </A>
</Root>
```

and

```
<Root>
    <A>
        <name>number</name>
        <value>15</value>
    </A>
</Root>
```

And I should to get the result XML:

```
<Root>
    <A>
        <name>number</name>
        <value>8</value>
    </A>
    <A>
        <name>number</name>
        <value>15</value>
    </A>
</Root>
```

I have my own solution is to get the object from XML, put it into a list and then get XML from this list. Maybe there is a better solution (using JAX-B)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge multiple files with JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49858160/merge-multiple-files-with-jaxb)

Comment: @Tygo, no, sorry

Comment: It shoub be jaxb method that get as params only two xml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to use JAXB for this, it seems over-complex.

You can do this with a one-line XQuery

```
<Root>{doc('A.xml')/*/*, doc('B.xml')/*/*}</Root>
```

Or with an only slightly longer XSLT:

```
<Root xsl:version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:copy-of select="document('A.xml')/*/* | document('B.xml')/*/*"/>
</Root>
```